# How do I render a component with the value of a state variable which is incremented with each render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I have a component in my React App.

I am looking to render this component repeatedly a number of times. The component has a className, which I want to set for each component with the value of the **'startOrFinishCellCount'** state. With each render the value should be incremented by 1.

I have tried a number of ways to do this, which have either led to infinite loops, or each component being rendered with the same state value.

How do I achieve what I have mentioned? Am I misunderstanding something about React?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './TimeUserInputTableData.css'

function TimeInputCell(props) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [startOrFinishCellCount, setStartOrFinishCellCount] = useState(0);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <td rowSpan={props.rowSpan} colSpan={props.colSpan}>
      <input
        type="time"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        id='timeInputCell'
        className={`timeInputCell${startOrFinishCellCount} h-100 w-100 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center`}
      />
    </td>
  );
}

export default TimeInputCell;
```

Comment: You can't rely on the number of times a component is rendered – React is at leisure to call your component as many times as it likes. What do you actually need to do? Why would you need the render count?

Comment: Oh – if this is for an array of similar inputs, then pass down the index as a prop from the component where you are rendering these inputs.

Comment: Yes it is for the purpose you outlined. I have a large amount of these inputs, which each relate to specific parts of my application. They need to be distinguished between each other to ensure each input is working for the specific part of the application it wants to interact with.

However what you outlined was a consideration I had. I just thought that might be too much code repetition and was looking for a more 'elegant' solution. But if you recommend that and see no issues in terms of practice, I could implement that!

Comment: There's no repetition: `{[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(i => <TimeInputCell key={i} index={i} />)`

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work! Thank you for your contribution, is there a way for me to accept an answer for you?

Comment: Posted as an answer :) Glad I could help.

Comment: Maybe show a full runnable example on https://codesandbox.io, so others can understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on the number of times a component is rendered – React is at leisure to call your component as many times as it likes.

Instead, if you need to e.g. render the same component multiple times, say for each day of the week, and you'd want each of them to have a different `className`, you'd pass in that index from the component rendering that component:

```
const days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
function WeekDisplay() {
  return (
    <>
      {days.map(day => <DayDisplay day={day} key={day} />)}
    </>
  );
}

function DayDisplay({day}) {
  return <div className={`day-${day}`}>Day {day + 1}</div>;
}
```

etc.